# How to retain URLs in pdfjoin?

Tags: macos, pdf

I am using `pdfjoin` to merge two pdfs. The first pdf has a "Click here" link which goes to a webpage. When I open the first pdf, I can click on the link which automatically opens my default browser and shows the webpage.

However, when I merge the two pdfs using `pdfjoin`, the "Click here" link has no effect and it just behaves as plain text in the final pdf.

How can I keep the effect of the URL using `pdfjoin`?

I am using OS X Yosemite and pdfjoin version 2.08.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at [PDFtk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/) which is available for GNU+Linux, macOS and Windows.  according to [this blog post](https://blog.dbrgn.ch/2013/8/14/merge-multiple-pdfs/) only PDFtk maintains hyperlinks, and i can confirm the findings when trying the same with pdfjam/pdfjoin.